# chrome packaged app not loading xhr images on android ever since cca 0.0.9

Tags: cordova, google-chrome-app, cordova-chrome-app

When I updated my cca from 0.0.7 to the latest my app stopped loading all external images only when running on android specifically.

My app allows users to specify avatars from other sites by pasting or sharing an image url, and I had been resizing the image in javascript and storing it in chrome local storage.   However I recently upgraded my cca and the external images no longer loaded on android.  Oddly enough, the chrome extension and the packaged ios version of the app load the external images fine.

By trying different versions of cca, I found that the behavior change is introduced in version 0.0.9 specifically.  Is anyone aware of a major change in cca 0.0.9 that has changed how xhr loaded resources or images are processed in android specifically?  I've gone through the [release notes](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md) for cca and it has some notes about host permission changes but I can't tell if that is specifically the problem.  Just wondering if other people have encountered the same issue and if there are any known workarounds, or even a way to identify the problem more specifically so I can escalate it to the cca developers.

Comment: FYI: cca latest is 0.1.1

Comment: Also, the release notes include updates to the underlying cordova-android platform, which may have had changes to whitelisting defaults (I don't recall for certain).  Does your chrome app run on desktop, or were you leveraging some cross-domain image request holes that used to exist on mobile only?

Comment: Yeah sorry i should have specified- this error seems to occur with all recent versions of cca, including the latest, 0.1.1.  I only specified version 0.0.9 because after extensive testing that seems to be the version that introduced the error for me.  My app does run on desktop, and also on ios.  It only manifests the problem on android.

Comment: Thanks that does help.  The release notes do not cover all of the changes that went in to the underlying cordova-android update, so I'll look to see what changed there.

Comment: cool- in the meantime i'll try to put together a gist that demonstrates the issue but my computer's internet has temporarily been taken out by a hurricane :/

Comment: I tried to strip my example down as much as possible, and I think it illustrates the issue I encountered when trying to display images loaded via XHR on android.  As I stated, the issue appears only on android, with cca versions >= 0.0.9.  On all versions of cca I tried, the issue did not manifest on ios.

https://github.com/infomofo/cca-demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've tracked this down to a problem with the way that CCA apps try to fix the hostname on `HTMLAnchorElement.href` attributes.

We added this code specifically for AngularJS on Android KitKat, to deal with `chrome-extension://` URLs, but it is failing in your specific case because you're converting the image into a data:// URL, and the code in CCA is throwing an exception when the regular expression fails to match it.

I've just now created an [issue](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/201) for this, and it will be fixed in the next release of `cca` (probably 0.1.2, hopefully RealSoonNow)